# Converting Java int-based amount to Coin metrics

Tags: java

I was tasked with writing a method which would take in an `int` (for amount in coins) and then convert the coins, accordingly, by counting how many quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies were located in the amount. Afterwards, it would return a `String` which stated each count of individual coin.

```
public class Coins {

    private static final int QUARTER_VALUE = 25;
    private static final int DIME_VALUE = 10;
    private static final int NICKEL_VALUE = 5;
    private static final int PENNY_VALUE = 1;

    public static String convert(int amount) {
        int currentAmount = amount;
        int quarters = 0;
        int dimes = 0;
        int nickels = 0;
        int pennies = 0;

        String quarterUnit = new String();
        String dimeUnit = new String();
        String nickelUnit = new String();
        String pennyUnit = new String();

        if (amount != 0) {
            quarters = amount / QUARTER_VALUE;

            currentAmount = 
                     amount - (quarters * QUARTER_VALUE);

            dimes = currentAmount / DIME_VALUE;

            currentAmount = 
                     amount - (quarters * QUARTER_VALUE) - (dimes * DIME_VALUE);

            nickels = currentAmount / NICKEL_VALUE;

            currentAmount = 
                     amount - (quarters * QUARTER_VALUE) 
                     - (dimes * DIME_VALUE) - (nickels * NICKEL_VALUE);

            pennies = currentAmount / PENNY_VALUE;
        }

        if (quarters == 1) {
            quarterUnit = " quarter";
        }

        else if (quarters > 1 || quarters == 0){
            quarterUnit = " quarters";
        }

        if (dimes == 1) {
            dimeUnit = " dime";
        }

        else if (dimes > 1 || dimes == 0) {
            dimeUnit = " dimes";
        }

        if (nickels == 1) {
            nickelUnit = " nickel";
        }

        else if (nickels > 1 || nickels == 0) {
            nickelUnit = " nickels";
        }

        if (pennies == 1) {
            pennyUnit = " penny";
        }

        else if (pennies > 1 || pennies == 0) {
            pennyUnit = " pennies";
        }

        StringBuilder conversion = new StringBuilder();

        return conversion.append(quarters)
                         .append(quarterUnit)
                         .append("\n")
                         .append(dimes)
                         .append(dimeUnit)
                         .append("\n")
                         .append(nickels)
                         .append(nickelUnit)
                         .append("\n")
                         .append(pennies)
                         .append(pennyUnit)
                         .append("\n")
                         .toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String conversionString = convert(89);

        System.out.println(
              new StringBuilder().append("Converted amount equates to: ")
                                 .append("\n"));

        System.out.println(conversionString);
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

> ```
> Converted amount equates to: 
>
> 3 quarters
> 1 dime
> 0 nickels
> 4 pennies
> ```

Is there a more efficient (fewer lines of code or a better OO style) way to implement this?

Comment: Hmm the unit names could be abbreviated to something like `nickelUnit = nickels==1 ? " nickel" : (nickels==0||nickels>1 ? " nickels" : "ERROR - negative amount of nickels!");` but I'm not sure you'd really gain much from that.

Answer (score 5):

Highlighting what a few helper classes can do :

Imagine this enum

```
private enum Coin {
    QUARTER(25, "quarter"), DIME(10, "dime"), NICKEL(5, "nickel"), PENNY(1, "penny", "pennies");
    ...
```

and a tuple of quotient and remainder :

```
private static class QuotientAndRemainder {
    private final int quotient;
    private final int remainder;
```

so the enum can sport this method :

```
public QuotientAndRemainder divide(int pennies) {
    return QuotientAndRemainder.quotient(pennies / pennyValue).withRemainder(pennies % pennyValue);
}
```

and this one :

```
public String format(int amount) {
    return Integer.toString(amount) + ' ' + (amount == 1 ? singular : multiple);
}
```

then the convert method simply becomes :

```
public static String convert(int amount) {
    return print(minimalChange(amount));
}

private static String print(Map<Coin, Integer> amounts) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Coin coin : amounts.keySet()) {
        builder.append(coin.format(amounts.get(coin))).append('\n');
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

private static Map<Coin, Integer> minimalChange(int amount) {
    int penniesLeft = amount;
    Map<Coin, Integer> amounts = new EnumMap<Coin, Integer>(Coin.class);
    for (Coin coin : Coin.values()) {
        QuotientAndRemainder quotientAndRemainder = coin.divide(penniesLeft);
        amounts.put(coin, quotientAndRemainder.quotient());
        penniesLeft = quotientAndRemainder.remainder();
    }
    return amounts;
}
```

Adding larger units of currency now simply comes down to adding them to the enum.

Comment: bowmore - Thank you for the valuable feedback! Your divide method inside the QuotientAndRemainder static class only pertains to pennies as does the minimalChange() method. How can I use this for other types of coins? Also, can you show me an example of how I can use these helper classes inside perhaps a main() method?

Comment: QuotientAndRemainder is a static class because I made it an inner class, which is not strictly necessary. `divide()` and `minimalChange()` pertain to an amount of pennies just as your original `convert()` method does. If your input would be an amount of coins then the `Coin` enum could also be given an 'int toPennies()' method. For my full code see http://ideone.com/jD666U

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not very Object Oriented, but it works.  This is a fine solution.  There are many ways you could make the code less verbose, or more Object Oriented, but that is besides the point.  I see nothing wrong with the way you implemented it.